# What's going with how python handles these JSON strings?

Tags: python, json, string

I've been struggling with a JSON response that's got all sorts of weird characters inside.

```
string_testing = '{"foo int":200,"body":"{\"foo bar"}'
string_testing = r'{}'.format(string_testing)
respose = json.loads(string_testing)
print(respose)
```

If the above code is run, it will not work and returns this error: *JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter*

However this does work:

```
string_testing = r'{"foo int":200,"body":"{\"foo bar"}'
respose = json.loads(string_testing)
print(respose)
```

Why? It should be practically the same code to the interpreter, but clearly it's not.

Comment: You can't make a non-raw string raw after the fact. `r` deals with how the bytes between the `""`s are parsed by the interpreter. So by the time you try to "add" `r`, the information (i.e. the escape character) is already lost.

Comment: Because `{"foo int":200,"body":"{"foo bar"}` is not valid JSON and `r'{}'.format(string_testing)` does nothing to change that... the "raw" string there is `'{}'`. A "raw string" isn't an operation you do on an object, it is a particular kind of *string literal*, an aspect of your source-code